# Jooq: Aliased tables and Record.into

Tags: java, sql, alias, java-8, jooq

I have two tables in my DB: `Client` and `Address`. `Client` references `Address` twice: as `BillToAddress` and `ShipToAdress`. I'd like to retrieve `Client` with his Addresses using jOOQ. That's my attempt:

```
public static Client fromRecord(Record record, Table<AddressRecord> billTo, Table<AddressRecord> shipTo) {
    return new Client(record.getValue(CLIENT.CLIENT_ID),
            AddressDao.fromRecord(record.into(billTo)),
            AddressDao.fromRecord(record.into(shipTo))
    );
}

public List<Client> loadAll() {
    superfirma.jooq.local.tables.Address billTo = ADDRESS.as("billTo");
    superfirma.jooq.local.tables.Address shipTo = ADDRESS.as("shipTo");
    return jooqContext.select().from(CLIENT)
                      .join(billTo).on(CLIENT.BILL_TO_ADDRESS_ID.eq(billTo.ADDRESS_ID))
                      .leftOuterJoin(shipTo).on(CLIENT.SHIP_TO_ADDRESS_ID.eq(shipTo.ADDRESS_ID))
                      .fetch(record -> fromRecord(record, billTo, shipTo));
}
```

It doesn't work: `record.into` matches by column names, not taking the (aliased) table name into account. From my quick look at jOOQ's code it just works that way (and I wonder why it doesn't work the way I want). The result is a Client with two identical addresses.

What's the alternative way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in jOOQ. I've registered [#3634](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3634) for this.

The issue appears only with aliased self-joins as the [`Record.into(Table)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#into-org.jooq.Table-) isn't able to distinguish between the two tables that originate from the same one. As a workaround, you could manually split the `record` into two before loading it into `AddressDao.fromRecord()` again.